# Filterable attribute not showing in filters

Tags: mysql, magento, filter

I have an attribute that is set to `Filterable (with results)` in `Use In Layered Navigation`.  I've reindexed, cleared cache, even turned off flat tables, but I can't get it to show up on the filters.

I've tracked down in the `catalog_product_index_eav` table all the other filterable attribute ids are in there but mine is missing.

I've tracked down this query in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute::_getItemsData()` which checks to see how many products there are for a given attribute.  If it's empty, it doesn't show the attribute

```
SELECT 
    `warehousecheckout_warehouses_idx`.`value`,
    COUNT(warehousecheckout_warehouses_idx.entity_id) AS `count`
FROM `catalog_product_flat_11` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index`
    ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id
    AND cat_index.store_id=11
    AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4)
    AND cat_index.category_id='11'
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index`
    ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1'
    AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `warehousecheckout_warehouses_idx`
    ON warehousecheckout_warehouses_idx.entity_id = e.entity_id
    AND warehousecheckout_warehouses_idx.attribute_id = '198' -- attr id i want to filter by
    AND warehousecheckout_warehouses_idx.store_id = '11'
GROUP BY `warehousecheckout_warehouses_idx`.`value`;
```

But there are no rows with `attribute_id = '198'` so the attribute is never shown.  Why isn't this attribute getting indexed?  It was created via an install script and not through the admin so it's possible a value somewhere was missed.

Comment: Did you set the -
 
     *category->display setting-> Is anchor set to "Yes"*

Comment: @Anx It's not a category.  It's an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight answer to this.
Go this way :

Remove other conditions and fire this query and check if you get your result then add one where condition and continue till you find where condition thats resulting in required row being eliminated.

What I see is that:
warehousecheckout_warehouses_idx.entity_id = e.entity_id
    AND warehousecheckout_warehouses_idx.attribute_id = '198' -- attr id i want to filter by
    AND warehousecheckout_warehouses_idx.store_id = '11'

also 
AND cat_index.category_id='11'

there are few more but
either category Id or store id should be the reason.

Comment: The 198 value doesn't exist in the idx table for any store.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to manually create the entries in the eav tables with

```
insert into catalog_product_index_eav
select entity_id, attribute_id, 1, value
from catalog_product_entity_varchar
where attribute_id = 198;

insert into catalog_product_index_eav_idx
select entity_id, attribute_id, 1, value
from catalog_product_entity_varchar
where attribute_id = 198;
```

You would have to do this for each store view.